How to interpret "implication holds" or "implication doesn't hold"?
Lets say we have a sentence, "If it is raining, then I will take the cab".
Let's say
$$
p: \text{It is raining} \\
q: \text{I will take the cab}
$$
In this if it is actually raining (confirmed by looking through the window) and the person takes the cab, then we say implication holds and implication is true.
And if it rains and person doesn't take the cab then we say implication does not hold, because $p \to q$ is false.How to interpret/digest/understand (idk the exact word) this thing intuitively without discussing the truth table in terms of the natural language?
I have used the example, but I want to know the meaning of implication holds or not in the abstracted sense.

In classical logic, one way to think about it is in terms of the material implication rule, which states that $p \rightarrow q$ is interchangable with $\neg p \vee q$.
Consider the statement: "If you keep talking, then I will punch you." (Note that all threats of violence are for illustrative purposes only, but I happen to like this example because it's visceral and gets the point across.)
If this threat is true, then three things could happen:

You could stop talking.
I could punch you.
Both. I never said I wouldn't.

The one thing that won't happen is that you keep talking and I do not inflict violence. Because, for the sake of this illustration, I'm apparently a horrible person.
Note that this is only true classically. In intuitionistic logic, $p \rightarrow q$ only means that if $p$ is provable, then so is $q$. No more and no less. Specifically, it says nothing if $p$ is not provable.
It's the same as if you had a function of type $f : A \rightarrow B$. If you  can find an element of $A$, that function will produce an element of the set $B$. But the function isn't of much use to you if you don't have an element of $A$ to feed it.

I like the example you have used.

The meaning of $p \to q$ is "if p then q" so you can just regard an implication statement as an if-else statement without ever mentioning the word "implies".
To verify that the implication $p \to q$ holds, you would verify that in all cases (statements? elements?) of your universe which satisfy $p$, they all satisfy $q$ as well.
If you find an example of an element in your domain where $p$ is true and yet $q$ is not true, then this shows the implication does not hold.

Since you mentioned if-else statement, could this "... then this shows the implication does not hold" be analogous to false boolean in if block triggering the else block? Then it would mean otherwise (actions when the if condition will be false) is also implied, which is not the case.

@tbhaxor no, not at all. the statement "then this shows the implication does not hold" would not be analogous to an else block. It would be analogous to stating that someone's if-else code is incorrect (i.e. flawed logic i.e. that the implication statement does not model the universe/domain being observed).
